# How to reposition chrome network tabs details view vertically?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Curently it is side by side as shown in image I want it to vertically side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's impossible (at least in the current stable version). If you think that such feature would be useful, you can report an issue in the [chrome bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: It was there before. I was using it. Since it got updated today it got re positioned this way.
It is more convenient when you have positioned debugger in vertical mode.